# Custom parameter need in createuser member in Custom Membership Provider in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-membership

I want to customize the parameter in createuser() method Membership Provider,

Actually, i have my own data store for users with different data including username,password.

but, the createuser() is not suite with my data

Any one can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your provider is the only one in use, you don't need to call your CreateUser method through ASP.NET at all. Just create the method anywhere and call it normally.

Comment: Thanks, if we are going to use own data store, do we need to use membership provider

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

```
using System;

namespace SampleApplication.Models
{
    using System.Web.Security;

    public class SampleMembershipUser : MembershipUser
    {
        public int UserLevelId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public TASMembershipUser(
            string providername,
            string username,
            object providerUserKey,
            string email,
            string passwordQuestion,
            string comment,
            bool isApproved,
            bool isLockedOut,
            DateTime creationDate,
            DateTime lastLoginDate,
            DateTime lastActivityDate,
            DateTime lastPasswordChangedDate,
            DateTime lastLockedOutDate,
            int userLevelId,
            string firstName,
            string lastName,
            string applicationName,
            Guid userId) :
            base(
                providername,
                username,
                providerUserKey,
                email,
                passwordQuestion,
                comment,
                isApproved,
                isLockedOut,
                creationDate,
                lastLoginDate,
                lastActivityDate,
                lastPasswordChangedDate,
                lastLockedOutDate)
        {
            UserLevelId = userLevelId;
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            ApplicationName = applicationName;
            UserId = userId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael is correct just thought that I would add some resources that helped me to undertake this task:

Great resource from Microsoft:

[How to: Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The other key thing to remember that is mentioned in the above link is that once you have done the work to create custom membership user and overloads for your methods like CreateUser is that where you call Membership.CreateUser you need to cast this to your custom membership provider like:

```
((CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).CreateUser(p1,p2 etc...)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you craigvl, your commented allowed me to access a custom public string on my custom MembershipProvider class.